# Função para encontrar palavra completa, mas independete da posição na string

Tags: r, string, regex, filter

Estou tendo problemas para utilizar o `str_detect` para capturar parte de um texto.

Preciso que o `str_detect` pegue apenas a palavra "alho", mas independente da posição dela na string. Ex: "alho brasileiro", "produtores de alho brasileiro" ou "fabricante de alho".

Exemplo:

```
str_detect(c("produção e trabalho","fabricante de alho",
             "alho brasileiro","produtores de alho brasileiro"),
             paste(c("carro", "futebol", 
              "^|[[:space:]]alho[[:space:]]|$"),collapse = '|'))
```

Neste exemplo, o `str_detect` está pegando as palavras "trabalho" e "alho".

--

É possível resolver com regex ou outra função?

Vou utilizar esta lógica para muitas palavras em um vetor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar `\b` ou `\<\>` para limitar o início e fim de uma palavra:

```
grep('\\balho\\b', c("produção e trabalho","fabricante de alho", "alho brasileiro","tem alho aqui"), value = TRUE)
grep('\\<alho\\>', c("produção e trabalho","fabricante de alho", "alho brasileiro","tem alho aqui"), value = TRUE)
```

FONTE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7227999/6532002

Comment: Excelente! Com `\\b` ficou show!